# Move a large instance method to shared, and create an instance stub -- good idea?

Tags: vb.net

Quick question: If I have a very large function/sub in a class that is an instance method (i.e., not `Shared`), do I gain or lose anything by moving that to a shared method and then declaring a small stub method for the instance use?

I.e., I go from this:

```
Public Sub MyBigMethod(ByVal Foobar As String)
    If String.IsNullOrWhitespace(Foobar) Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException("Foobar")
    End If

    ' Lots and lots of ugly code.
    ' Really.  There is lots of ugly code here.
    '
    ' Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
    ' elit. Aliquam vel erat sit amet massa ultricies
    ' adipiscing. Mauris eu est ligula, a pharetra lorem.
End Sub
```

To This:

```
Private Shared Sub MyBigMethod(ByVal Obj as MyObj, ByVal Foobar As String)
    ' Lots and lots of ugly code.
    ' Really.  There is lots of ugly code here.
    '
    ' Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
    ' elit. Aliquam vel erat sit amet massa ultricies
    ' adipiscing. Mauris eu est ligula, a pharetra lorem.
End Sub

Public Sub MyBigMethod(ByVal Foobar As String)
    If String.IsNullOrWhitespace(Foobar) Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException("Foobar")
    End If

    Call MyClass.MyBigMethod(Me, Foobar)
End Sub
```

My thinking is I save on memory size per each instance of the object.  Because each instance only has to lug around the stub method which handles calling the shared version and passing an instance of itself to the shared method so that it can do whatever it needs to do.  But I'll wager that I sacrifice a very teensy amount of speed because of the added function call overhead.

Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My thinking is I save on memory size per each instance of the object.

This is incorrect, because each instance does not store the method in memory. Instance methods are only stored in memory once. Function instructions are different than class members (which are stored per instance).

Furthermore, you gain a bit of a penalty by adding a function call, because the state of the stub method must be saved when calling the shared method. Then, it has to be loaded back when the shared method terminates. (Note: This is the same penalty you take when making any non-inline function call; the penalty becomes more stiff as the quantity and size of parameters increase)

You went down a logical line of thinking, but it was based upon the assumption that each instance gets its own logic instructions -- when they are actually used across all instances of a class.

Comment: Sounds a bit like how an interrupt handler works at the CPU level.  It just save the state of the thread it just interrupted, then restores them before returning.  So if my assumption is wrong, then nothing is gained whatsoever by making a large function a shared method?

Comment: @hamlin11: Re, third paragraph: What's the benefit then of a shared method on a class?  Only for cases where one deals with utility methods that do not need to operate directly on the instance variables of a class?

Comment: You actually gain some thread-safety problems with shared methods. As far as the CPU is concerned, there is no difference between shared and instance methods. It's just assembly language instructions. The compiler determines who gets access to those instructions before committing the program to assembly.

Comment: @hamlin11: I haven't had a need for threads yet.  But that is actually on my short list to tinker around with.  I suppose part of my mixup comes from how C uses static methods (from a kernel perspective).

Comment: Most of the time, you just need to think about shared/static members or functions in terms of "What do I need to do?". Does it apply to one object, or is it something that is at the class level? For example -- in a Product Class, the Save() function should be an instance function. However, Product.ReturnAllProducts() should be a shared function since it applies to all products. Some people use instance members / functions to track collective object information, such as ProductCountInMemory which could be incremented/decremented in constructors/destructors

Comment: @hamlin11: So an overridden `ToString` method might be a good candidate for Shared?  It doesn't need to manipulate any private members, just return the string version of the object.  Might this be applicable for the stub concept listed above?

Comment: Actually, it has to be instance -- because it accesses instance members (the object itself). Shared methods won't have access to instance members (variables). Basically, you have two classes of citizens. Instance Citizens can tweak the Shared Citizens, but not the other way around.  MyObject.ToString()  (You want that function to operate on your object). This would be a clumsy workaround: Product.ToString(MyProduct)

Comment: @hamlin11: That makes sense.  I also think I just dug up the bits on thread safety, and I think I know what's going on.  If I have `SomeSub` that is shared, and it takes an argument to work on, if, in the middle of its work, it were to get called again and handed a new argument to work on, is the execution of the original call going to finish w/o incident, or could this cause a concurrency problem?

Comment: This could cause a concurrency problem in a shared function if the function is accessing non-thread-safe data structures. .NET provides plenty of thread-safe data structures and there are some techniques such as semaphores that would allow you to access non-thread-safe data safely  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29

Comment: @hamlin11: Yeah, I am familiar with constructs such as spinlocks and the like.  Have not gotten into semaphores yet, though.  Not using threads either (might, but only in 1-2 spots), so I don't think I'll have problems.  Thanks for the pointers!